# A question about the convergence of a complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, summation, taylor-expansion

In my complex analysis textbook it says that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n $ converges for $|z|<1$.Even though it sounds reasonable to me (from my experience with real numbers) there is no proof about why this happens. Can somebody explain why for a number like $1+i$ the series above diverges and how we can find the radius of convergence in complex series? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, for a series to converge, the terms have to go to zero, and $\left|(1+i)^n\right|>1$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But How do we know that the radius of convergence for the given series is 1 ?

Comment: You can show it converges for $|z|<1$ since the partial sums of the series are $$\sum_{n=0}^N z^n=\frac{1-z^{N+1}}{1-z},$$ and $z^{N+1}\to 0$ when $|z|<1.$ And it can’t converge to when $|z|\geq1,$ because then $z^n$ does not converge to zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Okay now I understand how we found that $|z|<1$ in that specific case but is there any general method for finding the radius of convergence for any Taylor expansion?

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to find the radius of converge. The most general is the root test. But there are sometimes easier approaches like the ratio test. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test?wprov=sfti1